# How to unformat an accidentally formatted TryueCrypt partition?

Tags: data-recovery, formatting

So, I accidentally Quick Formatted a TrueCryptnon-system partition.

Is there any tool which will unformat it? To Widnwos, it would look like ea raw partition with no drive letter, so I am not sure that conventional unformatters will help.

I used the "Restore Volume Header" option in Truecrypts selected Restore using internal backup and gave my password and it mounted the disk as partition Z. At least, TrueCrypt thinks so, but Widows doesn't see any Z:

Have I lost it all?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.overclock.net/forum/20-hard-drives-storage/1507307-solved-truecrypt-formatted-recovery.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks (+1). I found it & tried it before posting this question. Alas, it does not help me. It seems like TrueCrypt itself recovered the partition, but Windows cannot see it :-(